# Access a joined table in C# and SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have this [image: Small Database] that is helping me store staff leave information.

I am able to create a new staff member and able to create a new leave object as well, how can I access the `staffleave` table so that I know which leave object is owned by which staff member?

Comment: How do you access data? Do you use entity-framework? Direct ADO.Net `SqlQuery`? Something else?

Comment: Are multiple staff members going to be related to the same leave?  Seems odd to me...    If so then it depends on your method of access as Louis pointed out.

Comment: I'm curious as to the purpose of the staffleave table to start with.  Why not just add staffId to the tblLeave and join from there?

Comment: Shouldn't the Leave table have a LeaveCategoryID in it? Can multiple people be attached to the same Leave? If not, then StaffID should just be a column in the Leave table.

Comment: it is a poor design in all aspects!!

Comment: Multiple people cannot be related to one leave object and i use sql query to accessnthe data,  what i want is to know which staff member is related to which leave object, or maybe i should revise my design. Now that i look at it tblLeave should have categoryId not the other way round.

Comment: @Sean i get what you mean, there is no need for staffLeave,

Comment: And I sure hope your password column is not plain text. Hopefully it is salted and hashed. :D

Comment: @Sean for the puporses of this project thst wont be necessary, :) i am actually very dissapointed since this design was given to us by our Teacher, mxxm,

Comment: WOW!!! Hopefully you can point out to your teacher the huge flaws in the design. There are many things that are not good in such a simple design. Kind of sad really.

Comment: Yeah Thanks for the advice,

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this as far I know

- using ADO.NET + TSQL query, so that you can write your TSQL that
  joins these two tables and fetch the desired results
- using Llinq that joins the tables, thus you don't have to write your
  TSQL